# How to generate dynamic menu tree using recursion in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, tree

Let say I have below menu picture in my mind.

[image]

According to the above picture I've created my SQL CTE query and the query
returning me the below result.

[image]

**Scenario**

The scenario is to create a multi level menu in ASP.Net webform application. In my past experience I've created menus using sitemap and menu control provided by the ASP.Net. But now I want to create custom menu using recursion on embedded code block.

**What I've tried yet?**

**site.master.cs**

```
public string recurseMenu(string ID = "0")
    {
        string s = "<ul id='ah-menu-level1'>";
        foreach (DataRow row in dtNavigation.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (row["Root_Navigation_ID"].ToString() == ID)
            {
                s += "<li><a class='ah-anchor-tooltip-show' href='javascript:void(0)'> <i class='fa " + row["CSS_Class"].ToString() + " fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i></a><ul class='sub-menu'><li><a href='javascript:void(0)'><strong>" + row["Name"].ToString() + "</strong></a></li>";

                if (row["ID"].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    s += recurseMenu(row["ID"].ToString());
                }
                s += "</ul>";
            }
        }
        return s += "</ul>";
    }
```

**site.master**

```
<% if (dtNavigation.Tables.Count > 0){%>
<%= recurseMenu() %>
<%}%>
```

Above code doesn't show me the desired result. It shows me the 1st level menu correctly but not submenus.

What I'm doing wrong in my code I couldn't find it. Please help me.

Comment: I've created a javascript version of your method and the recursion logic seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rexndacq/5/ . Both main menu and submenus seem to be generated. Maybe the structure (`ul`, `li`) that is generated are not fully correct? Or some CSS is hiding the submenus? If I were you, I would:
1) inspect the page with browser dev tools and analyse whether everything is on correct place
2) compare the generated html with any working menu you did in the past

Comment: @PJDev have a look on my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've figured this all out now, so I will answer my own question. Have a look on below code. If there is some other modification regarding optimization let me know.

**Output**

[image]

**site.master.cs**

```
public string AddTopMenuItems(DataTable dt)
    {
        string dHTML = "";
        DataView DataView = new DataView(dt);
        DataView.RowFilter = "Root_Navigation_ID = 0";
        foreach (DataRowView GetParentRow in DataView) //Filter and Iterate on those rows in which root id is zero.
        {
            dHTML += "<li><a class='ah-anchor-tooltip-show' href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='fa " + GetParentRow["CSS_Class"].ToString() + " fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
            dHTML += "<ul class='sub-menu'><li><a href='javascript:void(0)'><strong>" + GetParentRow["Name"] + "</strong></a>";
            NavigationItem item = new NavigationItem(GetParentRow["ID"].ToString(), GetParentRow["Root_Navigation_ID"].ToString(), GetParentRow["Name"].ToString());
            dHTML += AddChildMenuItems(dt, item);
            dHTML += "</li></ul></li>";
        }
        return dHTML;
    }

    private string AddChildMenuItems(DataTable dt, NavigationItem parentMenu)
    {
        EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> GetChildrens = from getChilds in dtNavigation.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                                        where getChilds.Field<Int64>("Root_Navigation_ID") == Convert.ToInt64(parentMenu.ID.ToString())
                                                        select getChilds; 
        DataView childs = GetChildrens.AsDataView();

        string retval = "";
        foreach (DataRowView child in childs)
        {
            NavigationItem subMenu = new NavigationItem(child["ID"].ToString(), child["Root_Navigation_ID"].ToString(), child["Name"].ToString());
            retval += "<ul><li><a href='javascript:void(0)'><strong>" + child["Name"].ToString().ToString() + "</strong></a>";
            retval += this.AddChildMenuItems(dt, subMenu);
            retval += "</li></ul>";
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

**site.master**

```
<% if (dtNavigation.Tables.Count > 0)
    { 
%>
        <ul id="menu">
        <%= AddTopMenuItems(dtNavigation.Tables[0]) %>
        </ul>
<% 
    } 
%>
```